# Back button is not working in two navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

[it is my first storyboard file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWvJG.png)In my application i have a navigation controller and i am using side menu and on every menu item a view controller open which has another navigation controller but when i press back button, it is not working.I am using storyboard. I think when new navigation open, stack of first navigation is lost. How to go back from second navigation controller?[it is second storyboard which open on side menu click but on second file view controller back button is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avn2x.png)

Comment: add code with description in question.

Comment: Hi Rajat, welcome to SO. Please take a moment and look into this to improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: proper describe your answer.Not understand question.